# Imports in Python3 packages -- is there a way to avoid writing the "dot"?

Tags: python-3.x, package

Let's say I have a file text.py with content

```
text = u'Wenn ist das Nunst\u00fcck git und Slotermeyer?'
```

and a file joke.py with content

```
from text import text    
def joke(): return text
```

which can be imported to another python script in the same directory. I want to convert it into a package and create the structure

```
/funniest
  setup.py
  /funniest
    joke.py
    text.py
```

For this to work, I need to add the *dot* `from .text import text` but then this of course doesn't work if some user wants to use it, within the `funniest/funniest` folder, in the old way

```
>> from joke import joke
```

Is there  a way to make the import so that it "works" both as a local import as well as within the package? (In Python2, it seems to work without the dots in both use-cases).

Or is it on purpose, to make a clear distinction between these use-cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a file `__init__.py` in funniest directory (same level as `text.py`). This will turn this directory into a (simple) python package.
Then you can write `from funniest.text import text` or
`import funniest.joke`.
In python 3 all imports are absolute except if you prepend at least one "." to indicate that is is relative.
It is to avoid inconsistency of python 2 which takes name as absolute if it does not found it as relative.

Your example is typically why this was done:
`from text import text`

"from text" is ambiguous: do you mean the "text.py" module in your current directory (relative) or the "text.py" module of python runtime library (absolute).

From within a module you can use relative import (with dot), outside, use absolute import.

If you want to have a script which has the same behavior in both python 2.7 and python 3, use:
`from __future__ import absolute_import`

This forces python 2 to act as python 3 for imports so writing import statements is consistent with both versions (provided your modules are written to work with both versions).

Comment: Thank you. But if I understand this correctly, the "from joke import joke" will still not work, if someone will not have the package installed, is that right? (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'funniest')

Comment: Yes.
Just copying a python file can be useful for your own usage, but if you want that others use it you should install it the right way. With setup.py, or simply copy the full funniest directory into a directory pointed at by your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.